# How to connect to MongoDB Sails.js. Getting connection 1 closed error

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, mongodb-atlas

I get the error MongoError: connection 1 to cluster0-shard-00-00.r7eql.mongodb.net:27017 closed
when I try to connect to my mongodb cluster. I already whitelisted my current IP Address because I saw that fixed problems in someone else's similar question. I was having issues with the .env variable, so this is my config in `datastores.js`

```
    // url: process.env.MONGODB_URL,
    host: 'cluster0-shard-00-00.r7eql.mongodb.net',
    port: '27017',
    user: 'dustin',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'v1?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-13rdfe-shard-0&authSource=admin&w=majority',
```

Comment: I also made sure in `production.js` to include the url string with the connection information in both the sections concerning the default datastore and session and it is still giving me that same error

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work finally. I believe it was because I have three shards on that cluster and in my connection string I was only saying to use one of them. I changed it to `'cluster0-shard-00-00.r7eql.mongodb.net,nextcluster,nextcluster'` and it worked